# Transforming data frame into multi-column data frame with NAs

Tags: r, dataframe

For example I have a data frame on the ratings of TV shows in three countries as below. I want to transform this data frame into a multi-column data frame with the values in the second column as column headers.

```
  Ratings  Countries
   102.71  Austria
   103.21  Austria
    ....
   103.87  Belgium
    ...
```

After transformation:

```
 Austria Belgium Canada
 102.71  103.87  470.49
 103.21  106.06  483.52
 109.86  114.1   492.41
 194.1   119.98  498.56
```

I know I can achieve this using function unstack(). However, the assumption of unstack() is each column has same number of rows. My problem is what if the numbers of ratings are different for different countries? In that way I want NAs to fill the spots. For example,

```
      Ratings  Countries
       102.71  Austria
       103.21  Austria
       103.87  Belgium
```

After transformation:

```
Austria Belgium 
 102.71  103.87  
 103.21  NA
```

I am not sure how to insert NAs to my transformation. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason that you want it to be a data frame? Usually, the rows have a meaning in a data frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a `tidyverse` approach:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% group_by(Countries) %>% mutate(id=1:n()) %>%
 pivot_wider(names_from = Countries, values_from=Ratings) %>% 
 select(-id)
```

The output:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  Austria Belgium
    <dbl>   <dbl>
1    103.    104.
2    103.     NA
```

Some data used:

```
df <- structure(list(Ratings = c(102.71, 103.21, 103.87), Countries = c("Austria", 
"Austria", "Belgium")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```